# Performance - how to capture all the Request in the Network tab of chrome in an automated way

Tags: performance, google-chrome, selenium, jmeter, webkit

I am in a process to capture all the request when an HTML page is loaded. My end goal is to create a report with the time taken for each individual request and also for the total time taken to load the entire page. I have tried to use the performance.getEntries() but it is limited to store only 150 request in the buffer. To overcome this I tried to set the performance.setResourceTimingBufferSize(size) but this buffer size is reset to default 150 when i refresh the page.

I would like to know the solution for below few things,

1. how to set the performance.setResourceTimingBufferSize(size) before loading any page (if I set it when the page is loading it misses to capture some of the request). Few suggested to set this in HTML head tag, but this is not possible in my case because i need to use selenium and i cant modify anything in source file.
2. I also found that we can save all the request as HAR file in chrome console. is there any way to do it in automated way?
3. Is there any other way to capture all the request ?

PS: I a using Jmeter (to simulate multiple users) to run the selenium scripts using web driver sampler. The automated way in the sense it should be done using selenium.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [BrowserMob proxy](https://bmp.lightbody.net/) in order to create and start a proxy server which will capture data and save it in form of .har

1. Download BrowserMob proxy and put .jar files somewhere into [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
2. Restart JMeter to pick the .jars put
3. In [setUp Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group) add [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and put the following code into "Script" area

   ```
   import net.lightbody.bmp.BrowserMobProxy
   import net.lightbody.bmp.BrowserMobProxyServer
   import net.lightbody.bmp.proxy.CaptureType

   def proxy = new BrowserMobProxyServer()
   def captureTypes = new HashSet<>();
   captureTypes.addAll(CaptureType.getAllContentCaptureTypes());
   captureTypes.addAll(CaptureType.getHeaderCaptureTypes());
   captureTypes.addAll(CaptureType.getCookieCaptureTypes());
   proxy.setHarCaptureTypes(captureTypes);
   proxy.start(8080)
   proxy.newHar()

   props.put('proxy', proxy)
   ```
4. Set up your [Chrome Driver Config](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ChromeDriverConfig/) to use proxy from the step 3

   [image: JMeter Configure Proxy]
5. Add [tearDown Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) to your Test Plan and in another JSR223 Sampler use the following code to store requests made by the WebDriver Sampler(s) into a .har file:

   ```
   def proxy = props.get('proxy')
   proxy.getHar().writeTo(new File('some.har'))
   proxy.stop()
   ```

That's it, now you should have .har file generated during test execution.

References:

- [BrowserMob Proxy: Embedded Mode](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy#embedded-mode)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri. As i mentioned before the goal is to take a report for time take to load every request and also for the entire page. If I use proxy, will it cause some time delay since each request needs to go through the proxy? I should get the load time similar to the time displayed in network tab of the browser. Please advise.

Comment: You have either this way, which is easier, or an external sniffer tool like [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org/) which is harder. It is up to you to decide, proxy itself will have zero impact on the har file, it will add few milliseconds to what [WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler) measures, the overhead will be minimal and won't have any impact.

Comment: Thank you. let me try with the proxy. Just a quick question before i dig deep into the proxy. Is there any possibility to create har file per page ? For example, i dont need to create a single har file for all the page navigation. each page navigation should get a separate har file so that it will be easier to process

Comment: Hi Dmitri, I downloaded browsermob-proxy-2.1.4 from the link you provided and placed browsermob-core-2.1.4-sources,browsermob-rest-2.1.4-sources and browsermob-dist-2.1.4.jars under JMeter lib folder. Then afterwards, when I open JMX, `2018-04-16 18:48:56,265 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.addPermission(Lcom/thoughtworks/xstream/security/TypePermission;)V` is displayed. When I try to create a new and run it, `Could not initialize class org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService` exception is displayed.

Comment: @DmitriT, I have added JSR223 as a Post processor to each sampler to generate har file. This works fine for single user. How can I achieve the same for multiple users ??. I want to generate single har file for multiple threads. I tried with Synchronizing timer, but still no use. Kiindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

For your goal, you can try https://gtmetrix.com/. This will give you a report for the load time and all the requests in waterfall model like in browser. Moreover, you can download the full report in pdf and can do compare and retest.
There you can also download the HAR file.

Though, it is not related to selenium but may fit your goal and It can be automated.